# Family Photo Gallery Questions

Tags: image, authentication, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

I recently did this Django tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSquD2u5Ie0

It was very informative, but I had a few questions that I wanted to answer:

1. Instead of S3 Buckets, I wanted to use my internal server to host the media. Is there anything I need to change in the MEDIA ROOT folder? Or can I save it under Static files still? The full website will be hosted on a ubuntu server.
2. Any advice on how to update or delete images?
3. How can I use multiple catagories?
4. I wanted to add a login page, but I don't want anyone just to be able to sign in. I want to only give out sign in codes to my family. Could I just create their user page info and create a user login page?

Thanks, any advice would be helpful.

I haven't tried anything yet